# Periodically log gradients without requiring two functions (or slowdown) in Theano

Tags: theano

For diagnostic purposes, I am grabbing the gradients of the network periodically. One way to do this is to return the gradients as output of the theano function. However, copying the gradients from the GPU to CPU memory every time may be costly so I would prefer to do it only periodically. At the moment, I am achieving this by creating two function objects, one which returns the gradient and one which doesn't.

However, I do not know whether this is optimal and am looking for a more elegant way to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Your first function obviously executes a training step and updates all your parameters.

The second function must return the gradients of your parameters.

The fastest way to do what you are asking is to add the updates for the training step to the second function and when logging the gradients, don't call the first function, but only the second.

```
gradients = [ ... ]
train_f = theano.function([x, y], [], updates=updates)
train_grad_f = theano.function([x, y], gradients, updates=updates)
num_iters = 1000
grad_array = []
for i in range(num_iters):
   # every 10 training steps keep log of gradients
   if i % 10 == 0:
       grad_array.append(train_grad_f(...))
   else:
       train_f(...)
```

---

Update

if you wish to have a single function to do this, you can do the following

```
from theano.ifelse import ifelse

no_grad = T.iscalar('no_grad')
example_gradient = T.grad(example_cost, example_variable)

# if no_grad is > 0 then return the gradient, otherwise return zeros array
out_grad = ifelse(T.gt(no_grad,0), example_gradient, T.zeros_like(example_variable))

train_f = theano.function([x, y, no_grad], [out_grad], updates=updates)
```

So when you want to retrieve the gradients you call

```
train_f(x_data, y_data, 1)
```

otherwise

```
train_f(x_data, y_data, 0)
```

Comment: as mentioned in my original answer - this is what I'm currently doing. But it seems suboptimal as it is compiling two graphs?

Comment: I apologize, it was unclear in your question, that the second function actually applied a training step. I believe that theano is smart enough to understand it is the same graph and actually reuses the work done in the compilation of the first function to speedup the second. Have you tried timing the first vs the second function compilation?

Comment: I updated my answer on how to do this with a single function, in case there are compilation time differences